# Adding (flat rate) shipping costs to the magento grand total in the shopping cart - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, cart, magento-1.9

Currently my magento shopping cart only adds up all the prices of the products in the cart. Adds this up to a subtotal, and then displays the exact same amount to the grand total. This is not realistic, since I will charge a flat rate amount of shipment costs (Will always be the same amount: 5,95)

Administratively, I use prices excluding tax, to keep things simple. I will state in the bottom of the site that all prices are inclusive of tax.

I have been looking around, but no one seems to have this problem, or there are no answers.

So what I have now:
Subtotal: 22,50
Grand total: 22,50

What I would like:
Subtotal: 22,50
Shipping: 5,95
Grand total: 28,45

Comment: can you please share screenshot that flatrate shipping is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‘Subtotal’ and ‘Grand total’ are fetched from

app\design\frontend\your-package\ your -theme\template\ tax\checkout\subtotal.phtml file and grandtotal.phtml files respectively. 
    Edit grandtotal.phtml file as per your need.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this soon. I have not had the time yet. However, I do value your input and will try this soon.

Comment: I hacked it in. I had to hardcode the flatrate to show it and also add it in php to the getTotal. This is the best answer I got, thanks. Even though I hoped there would be a graceful way to fix it. ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you entered the flat rate price correctly in the backend?  Could you provide screenshots of that setting and also, how does you tax settings look? Check under

www.theshop.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/tax/

For tax settings related to the shipping cost.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this soon. I have not had the time yet. However, I do value your input and will try this soon.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I checked everthing but there were no flaws in the flatrate.